# Question about PrimeZetaP

Tags: special-functions, number-theory

The [`PrimeZetaP`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimeZetaP.html) function appears to give results for complex `s` with real part > 0. Apparently, the analytic continuation is built into the programming. Can anyone explain the mathematical calculation behind this function for $0<\sigma\leq 1?$ The analytic continuation of `Zeta[s]` is explained in many texts, but that is not the case for the so-called prime zeta function. I looked at the [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html), which links to a paywalled article, and looked at the online *Mathematica* guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discussed the prime zeta function at some length in [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/84646). In particular, the infinite Möbius inversion

$$P(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{k}\log\zeta(ks)$$

is the actual computational formula used, as recommended in [Fröberg's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01933420). (It is also noted there that numerical evaluation becomes more difficult at values near the imaginary axis, where there is a dense fence of singularities.)

Comment: Will check the MSE answer. It's valid on (0,1] then I take it?

Comment: Yes, except at singular points, of course.